# stopping fibonacci input negatiive

Tags: php

so i have made a fibonacci cycle but i need to make it stop when it hits a certain number and it must get higher than that. That part is not the problem mine problem is that i made a html where you can input the number but when you put in a negative number it doesnt do anything can someone help me
here is mine code

```
$a=0;
$b=1;
$c=$_POST["fibi"];




    for ($i = 0; $i <= $c; $i++) {

        $z = $a + $b;
        echo $z."<br />";

        if ($c == 0){

            echo 'the highest number is 0';
            break;

            }elseif($c < 0){

                echo "please enter a positive number";
                break;
        }
            elseif($z >= $c){

                echo "the highest number is $latest";
                break;
            }


        $latest = $z;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $z;

            }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>fibi</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="fibi.php" method="post">
            input:<input type= "number" name="fibi"> </form><br>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You should really do your homework assignments on your own.

Comment: Always sanitize user input. in that case make sure, it's a positive integer. And do that _before_ you start using that variable.

Comment: i don't even see php tags on the code block.  <?php   ?>

Comment: [`isset`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjS5bSlx4vLAhUHThQKHeSHB2sQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.isset.php&usg=AFQjCNEilnOC2VNydDdQDAXjnJjWAYf6Mg&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGg), [`empty`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj93sumx4vLAhVGxxQKHaLcClIQFgiYATAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.empty.php&usg=AFQjCNFOSUbVb_y7NH0-x51nm-gQ4YFk2A) and [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) are your friends for validation.

Comment: What action do you want perform if the input is negative?

Comment: if the input is negative i what it to echo something like i tried with elseif($c < 0){

                echo "please enter a positive number";
                break; but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition like `if($c > 0)` around your code.